# Update PHP mail code to use SMTP instead of php mail() function

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer, html-email

I have a php code file used in website to handle sending emails from the web app using the mail() function in php.

I decided to use SMTP instead of that want you to check that the variables of old code is used on the new SMTP one

Here are the code

```
<?php

// please only use the fields thata re present in the html form itself for now we have listed all possible ones

//// NEW CODE ////
require '../mail/PHPMailerAutoload.php';


$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.domain.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'username';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'password';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'SSL';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
'ssl' => array(
'verify_peer' => false,
'verify_peer_name' => false,
'allow_self_signed' => true
)
);

$mail->setFrom('hello@example.com', 'Name');
$mail->addAddress('maher@domain.com', 'Location');     // Add a recipient                              // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('hello@example.com', 'Name');
//$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
//$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

//$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
//$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
echo 'Message could not be sent.';
echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo 'Message has been sent';
}

//// OLD CODE ////

$to = "maher@domain.com";
if (isset($_POST)){

    $subject = "location system email";

    if ($_POST['fullname'] ! =''){
        $message = "Fullname: " . $_POST['fullname'];
    } else {
        $message = "First name: " . $_POST['fname'];
        $message = "Last name: " . $_POST['lname'];
    }
    $message .= "<br>Phone: " . $_POST['Phone'];
    $message .= "<br>Website: " . $_POST['website'];
    $message .= "<br>Email: " . $_POST['email'];
    $message .= "<br>Message: " . $_POST['message'];

};

$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: " . $_POST['fullname'] . " <" . $_POST['email'] . ">". "\r\n";

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ) {
    echo "ok";
} else {
    echo "error";
}
```

I want to use the old code variables and apply it ot work with the new SMTP code.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have any issue in code?

Comment: I want to delete the old code and use the stmp new one. I am not very familiar with php and I think that the variables in old code shall be updated in the new part because it send email using a web form.

Comment: Did you get this working Ahmed? Ive just implemented PHPMailer on my website and am in process of replacing mail(). If not, I can add another answer

Answer (score -1):

The question is not very clear, but from what I understood here is the solution :)

In case you want to replace the default mail() function with PHPMAILER:

1. Then you have to first install the phpmailer library in the root directory (or anywhere but while including/referring to the files in your code, please ensure the path is correct) of your code base.
2. Once this is installed, you go to the code where mail() function is called. There replace the mail() function with the code sample which you shared above.
3. Then replace the following variable in the code:

   $mail->Host = 'smtp.domain.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers

   $mail->Username = 'username';                 // SMTP username

   $mail->Password = 'password';                           // SMTP password

   $mail->Port = 465;

Go for API based email sending code library in case you're finding challenges with the SMTP one.